# Using a regular expression to match everything after a colon

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I've got a string like this:

```
192.168.114.182:SomethingFun-1083:EOL/Nothing Here : MySQL Database 4.12
192.168.15.82:SomethingElse-1325083:All Types : PHP Version Info : 23
```

I'm trying to select this item in an Oracle database (using REGEXP_SUBSTR) and get all remaining text after the second colon (:).

So in the end, I'd like to get these values:

```
EOL/Nothing Here : MySQL Database 4.12
All Types : PHP Version Info : 23
```

I've tried these, but it haven't found something that works.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(title,'[^:]+',1,3) as Title -- doesn't work if last field has ":"
REGEXP_SUBSTR(title,'(?:[^:]*:)+([^:]*)') as Title
```

Comment: A much better alternative would be to split the string and use the parts: http://www.dbforums.com/oracle/998642-pl-sql-splitting-string-into-array.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

how about `REGEXP_REPLACE`

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(title,'^[^:]+:[^:]+:(.*)$', '\1') as Title
```

Comment: I'm new to Oracle and didn't know about this function, worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Oracle's regular expression functions tend to be CPU intensive versus alternatives. Tom Kyte's advice is "[however, if you can do it without regular expressions - do it without them. regular expressions consume CPU hugely.](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1794145000346577404#1794911900346530802)"

An alternative not using regular expressions would be `substr(test_values, instr(test_values, ':', 1, 2) + 1)`

```
SQL> create table t (test_values varchar2(100));

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values ('192.168.114.182:SomethingFun-1083:EOL/Nothing Here : MySQL Database 4.12');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ('192.168.15.82:SomethingElse-1325083:All Types : PHP Version Info : 23');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select substr(test_values, instr(test_values, ':', 1, 2) + 1)
  2  from t;

SUBSTR(TEST_VALUES,INSTR(TEST_VALUES,':',1,2)+1)
-----------------------------------------------------
EOL/Nothing Here : MySQL Database 4.12
All Types : PHP Version Info : 23
```

Bench-marking left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
^[^:]+:[^:]+:(.*)$
```

Comment: Might wanna drop the slashes as it's Oracle regex.

Comment: Seems like this should work, but I still get back the entire line as if the whole line matched.
    `REGEXP_SUBSTR(Title,'^[^:]+:[^:]+:(.*)\$') as Title, --using a slash in front of $ because of Perl`

Comment: I put actual data I'm working with in a regex parser and this regex gets me the data I need. Looks like I may have a problem with my Oracle statement returning the entire line instead of the matched content.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had to fix a syntax error on my side to get the regex to work.

Comment: I don't think REGEXP_SUBSTR works they way it would intuitively seem like it should. REGEXP_REPLACE does it - see @bpgergo's answer.